# Please explain the ps -aef response on RHEL

Tags: host, rhel, ps

What does pts/2 indicate in the below output. Why there is no such for other dd processes?

```
$ ps -aef |grep dd
    root  6553672 15073352   3 02:32:19      -  0:01 dd of=/dev/lv01 bs=1024k
  padmin  9437410 16515110   1 02:43:32  **pts/2**  0:00 grep dd
    root 13828156 11010220   0 02:32:33      -  0:00 dd of=/dev/lv02 bs=1024k
    root 14155860 13828156   2 02:32:33      -  0:01 dd of=/dev/lv02 bs=1024k
    root 15073352 13762812   0 02:32:19      -  0:00 dd of=/dev/lv01 bs=1024k
    root 15532200 15925276   2 02:40:47  **pts/1**  0:03 dd of=/home/padmin/sample-dd-op bs=1024k
```

Comment: This is not a Programming related question. You should better ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Yes, it is a programming question. Super User is for general end-user desktop computing questions ("How do I change my password?") RHEL is a server OS. The `ps` command is something of interest to programmers. Just because you aren't aware of that doesn't make the question "off topic." This question is perfectly valid and legit for S.O. Leave it open.

Answer (score 0):

pts/X in the TTY column means that the process is connected to a `pseudo terminal slave`.

An empty value means:

- The terminal session has ended
- The command was fired by a daemon

[This nice Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21294/43090) shows the difference between PTS and TTY.